# How to save retrived URLs in a xml file using php?

Tags: php, xml

I can store normal string. But if I tried to store `GET` method url it can not store.

```
function updateX_xml($id,$val,$addre){

    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('autoGen/autoGen.xml');
    $node = $xml->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0) ;
    $xml_id = $xml->createElement("id");
    $xml_addres = $xml->createElement("Address");
    $domAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('type');
    $domAttribute->value = 'xs:string';
    $xml_addres->appendChild($domAttribute);
    $xml_url = $xml->createElement("url");
    $xml_id->nodeValue=$id;
    $xml_url->nodeValue=$val;
    $xml_addres->nodeValue=$addre;
    $node->appendChild( $xml_id );
    $node->appendChild( $xml_url );
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->save("autoGen/autoGen.xml");
}
```

if i call this function like this `updateX_xml(1,'getdata?event_id=1 &lan=en',"addaress");` it is not working.

This will generate this warning. **Warning: updateX_xml(): unterminated entity reference lan=en in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_file_read\gen_url.php on line 25**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting something into XML/HTML you should always use the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function. this will escape your strings into correct XML syntax.

So:

```
function updateX_xml($id,$val,$addre)
{
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('autoGen/autoGen.xml');
    $node = $xml->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0) ;
    $xml_id = $xml->createElement("id");
    $xml_addres = $xml->createElement("Address");
    $domAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('type');
    $domAttribute->value = 'xs:string';
    $xml_addres->appendChild($domAttribute);
    $xml_url = $xml->createElement("url");
    $xml_id->nodeValue=$id;
    $xml_url->nodeValue = htmlspecialchars($val);
    $xml_addres->nodeValue=$addre;
    $node->appendChild( $xml_id );
    $node->appendChild( $xml_url );
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->save("autoGen/autoGen.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without space between parameters:

```
updateX_xml(1,'getdata?event_id=1&lan=en',"addaress");
```

Also, as others mentioned, you need to escape the "&", as it's a special character in xml using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) :

```
 $xml_url->nodeValue = htmlspecialchars($val);
```

Comment: You also need to escape special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape HTML entity character:

```
$val= htmlentities($str, ENT_XML1);
    $xml_url->nodeValue=$val;
```